# Dynamically set value in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I would like to set a value dynamically based on the system memory information gathered by ohai/facter. Sorry if this should be obvious but I am new to ansible.

In chef I would do the following:

```
jvm_heap = "#{(node.memory.total.to_i * 0.6 ).floor / 1024}m"
```

Answer (score 2):

Some facts gathered from ansible in the setup, are listed in the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#information-discovered-from-systems-facts).

To answer your question, you would do something very similar to what you are doing in chef:

```
$ cat template.j2
jvm_heap = {{ ansible_memtotal_mb *0.6 / 1024 | int }}
```

`ansible_memtotal_mb` as you can guess contains the value, in MB of the total memory.

The `{{ ... }}` Syntax is Jinja2 syntax, which is what ansible uses to render your templates.

Answer (score 0):

ansible uses jinja2 templating library, you can find more information on how to use a variable in the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html).

Here is an example:

```
- hosts: app_servers
  vars:
      app_path: {{ myvariable }}
```

Note: It can't run maths functions for you; you should give it a precomputed value.